# O que é um algoritmo Backtracking?

Tags: algoritmo, ciência-da-computação

O que é um algoritmo **Backtracking** ?

- Quais suas características ?
- Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens ?

Comment: Na boa não conhecia, achei isso aqui no Wikipedia https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking e achei super foda.

Comment: @Marconi elabora uma resposta construtiva e poste aqui !

Comment: Vou deixar essa pros mais experientes,rs. Já marquei até como favorita pra ver quando sair a resposta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Backtracking** é um algoritmo genérico que busca, por força bruta,
soluções possíveis para problemas computacionais (tipicamente
problemas de satisfações à restrições).

- De maneira incremental, busca por candidatos à soluções e abandona
  cada candidato parcial C quando C não pode resultar em uma solução
  válida.
- Quando sua busca chega a uma extremidade da estrutura de dados,
  como um nó terminal de uma árvore, o algoritmo realiza um retrocesso
  tipicamente implementado através de uma recursão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo de Algoritmo**

```
bool acabou = FALSE;

backtrack(int a[], int k, int n) {
    int c[MAXCANDIDATOS];  /* Candidatos para a próxima posição */
    int ncandidatos;       /* Número de candidatos para a próxima posição */
    int i;                 /* Contador */

    if (e_uma_solucao(a, k, n)) {
        processar_solucao(a, k, n);
    } else {
        k = k + 1;
        construir_candidatos(a, k, n, c, &ncandidatos);
        for (i=0; i<ncandidatos; i++) {
            a[k] = c[i];
            backtrack(a, k, n);
            if (acabou) return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Características Básicas:**

- Para cada chamada recursiva existem diversas opções que podem ser seguidas. Ex.: Muitos vértices
  podem ser o próximo.
- Diversos dados do subconjunto de dados de entrada ainda não incluídos na solução são candidatos.
  Pode ser que todos sejam e pode existir uma restrição (constraint) reduzindo o número de
  candidatos. Ex.: Só vértices vizinhos são candidatos a serem o próximo.
- O algoritmo pode tentar uma chamada recursiva para cada um dos candidatos (solução para
  pesquisa exaustiva). Ex.: O Caixeiro Viajante tenta todos os caminhos.
- O algoritmo pode escolher um ou poucos dados segundo um critério qualquer.
- O processo de busca cria uma árvore de chamadas recursivas. Ex.: Todos os caminhos parciais do
  caixeiro viajante.
- Folhas dessa árvore são de dois tipos:

  - Representam uma possível solução para o problema.
  - Representam um ponto onde o algoritmo não pôde mais ir adiante (failure) sem ferir alguma
    pré-condição para que a solução gerada até então seja válida. Ex.: Caminho encontrado até
    agora é muito longo, embora ainda existam vértices por percorrer.

**Pontos Positivos:**

- Forma bastante fácil de implementar um problema que de outra forma seria muito mais complexo de
  se resolver.
- Linguagens da Área de Programação em Lógica (PROLOG, KL-ONE, OPS5) geralmente trazem algum mecanismo embutido que dá suporte ao backtracking.

**Pontos Negativos:**

- Programas de backtracking, a não ser que se programe restrições (constraints) executam sempre
  uma busca exaustiva e tenderão à explosão combinatória.
- Programas de Backtracking são por natureza, Combinatórios !
- Necessitam de muita memória no Stack, já que a quantidade de variáveis locais transportada por
  cada chamada recursiva é diretamente proporcional ao tamanho do problema.
- Isto significa que a quantidade de memória requerida para um programa de backtracking pode
  crescer exponencialmente com o tamanho do problema.

**Onde é aplicável:**

Backtracking é aplicável na solução de vários problemas conhecidos, dentre os quais podem-se destacar:

- Caixeiro Viajante
- Passeio do Cavalo
- N-Rainhas
- Encontrar Espaço de Soluções
- Exame de Graham
- Geração de Permutações
- Problemas de labirinto

**OBS: Deve-se ficar atento a explosão combinatória.**

> Fonte: [Backtracking](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Comment: Aparentemente você retirou a figura e o exemplo da Wikipédia, seria importante dar os devidos créditos. Além disso, o exemplo é mais um snippet do que uma demonstração do algoritmo, pois nem é pseudocode. Qual é a linguagem?